# Will it impact SEO to use Flexbox to move text up in the page source code but leave it further down the rendered page?

Tags: seo, html, css

With Flexbox, it's easy to reorder content in page and put SEO content in the top of the page for robots and reorder page block to put that content in the bottom of the page for users.

Is it worth it?

Here is a snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/1rc464vx/

```css
.flex {
display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
#seocontent{
  order:2
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of my page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="flex">
<header>
    <nav>
        <strong>My menu</strong>
    </nav>
</header>
  <section id="seocontent">
    <h1>Seo Content (appear first to robots and last to users)</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
</section>
<section id="maincontent">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio cum ipsa quidem beatae ipsam a soluta debitis aspernatur autem rerum laboriosam natus harum ut velit quasi, fugit error, minus nihil.

</section>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Flex is for users, not search engines. Also it has been possible to reorder elements without Flex, Bootstrap and ZURB foundation has been using Push / Pull grids for several years. Google doesn't just look at the source code, it can also render the page to see how its presented to users.

Comment: Ok, but do you think there is a positive impact foe SEO ?

Comment: There are not any advantages or disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

Ten years ago, getting content near the top of the page source code was important.  Back then Googlebot was much less sophisticated.  It just assumed that content near the top of the source was important.

Today Googlebot actually renders pages.  It pays attention to CSS and JavaScript.   Content that appears to users prominently is deemed more important that content to which users need to scroll.

I don't think that Googlebot even pays attention to source code order anymore.

Comment: but as further down the seo content i placed, as higher is the unlucky possibility, that the bot makes use of any link before and goes away - thats why it will be always recommendable to place seo content as closer to opening body as possible. Beside of this, there are many citation of Google employees to think about a webpage as about a book - thinking so, the most important content must be published firstly.

Comment: There is certainly evidence that text after 100k doesn't get indexed.  Other than that important text should come first for users to get the most attention from Google.

Comment: Could you provide any sources to back this up?

Comment: Google has documentation about how Googlebot fetches and renders pages.  Google even provides a tool in Google Search Console that lets you see your site as rendered by Googlebot: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Flex is presentation, not content. Search engines care about content, not presentation, unless you are trying to hide something.

You may, however, run into problems when you present content in a different fashion to search engines versus users. Search engines don't like to be treated differently because it gives the impression you are trying to trick them. In your case, it looks to me like you are trying to trick them.

The exception may be that you aren't changing the order of the HTML and content using Flex. Nor are you hiding the content. But any time you try manipulating things for search engines, you run a risk of getting penalized.

Comment: Actually it is applied when website purpose is, only to manipulate search engine. You might already seen that. most of sidebar are displayed at bottom when device size is getting lower, and it completely fine. So I don't think pattern of content position will make OP into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

try to achieve, that the initially loading site's code has the seo content as near as possible to the opening `<body>`. What users will do with, how they will rearrange your boxes isn't important - main thing, that the crawler, if coming, gets your seo content as fast as possible.