# CSS Flex Order, What Does Googe Use?

Tags: seo, css, meta-description, flex

If I have a page with four rows of content in the HTML ordered as:

- Topic C
- Topic A
- Topic B
- Topic D

Then using CSS I reorder them into ABCD for desktop and DABC for mobile, which row will Google use for the page description?

Comment: My experience is that Google chooses it's own page description many times.  Sometimes it's from my meta tags, sometimes it's the first paragraph/sentence, other times it's from somewhere in the middle of the page.  Just ask yourself, if an AI could read your content in any order and write a brief page description.

Comment: Stephen provided a helpful answer here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/100043/will-it-impact-seo-to-use-flexbox-to-move-text-up-in-the-page-source-code-but-le